# unexpectedly found nil when switching to another view controller when search bar is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have two view controllers that both have a search bar and a table view. They have the same data but different cell layouts. The first view controller is `SearchBarViewController` and when a cell is selected to segues the next view controller, which is `SearchesViewController`. I wan't to go back to `SearchesViewController` because they're need to be different cells.

SearchBarViewController didselectRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let searchesVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchesViewController") as? SearchesViewController
    searchesVC?.search = [search[indexPath.row]]
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchesVC!, animated: true)
    
}
```

SearchesViewController searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false
    self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: SearchBarViewController()), animated: false, completion: nil)
    
}
```

I keep getting a `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` in `tableView.delegate = self`. Any would be appreciated!

where crash occurred:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self //CRASH
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    retriveData()
    print(search)
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of present you need to pop controller

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false
     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    
}
```